CSS Scroll Snap And Smooth Scroll With Location Hash Broken
CSS Scroll Snap And Smooth Scroll With Location Hash Broken
In Google Chrome version 125.0.6422.113 (64-bit) there seem to be two issues. This only seems to occur when using CSS Scroll Snap.

When clicking on an Internal Bookmark (#bookmark) that is a snap element, Smooth Scroll breaks.
After navigating to a Scroll Snap element (above) and then to a non snap element, the location.hash changes but the page doesn't scroll to the element until clicking it a 2nd time.


The screencapture above shows a link to 6 Internal Bookmarks: 4 non snap elements (indices 0,1,2,4) and 2 snap elements (indices 3, 5 [blue bg & black footer]).
Question 1
Are these bugs in Google Chrome?
Question 2
Has anyone come up with a workaround for these 2 issues?
